# How can I fix this 403 Forbidden error when web-scraping in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, http-status-code-403

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(httr)
```

```
# URL
link <- "https://www.congress.gov/search?q=%7B%22source%22%3A%22nominations%22%2C%22congress%22%3A118%7D"

# Make the request
page <- read_html(link)
```

Extract

```
name <- page %>% html_nodes(.result-heading strong)%>% html_text()
lastest_action<- page %>% html_nodes(.result-item:nth-child(6))%>% html_text()
date_receieved <- page %>% html_nodes(.result-item span)%>% html_text()
committee <- page %>% html_nodes(.result-item:nth-child(5))%>% html_text()
description <- page %>% html_nodes(.result-heading+ .result-item)%>% html_text()
number <- page %>% html_nodes(.result-heading a)%>% html_text()
```

Data Frame

```
congress <- data.frame(name, lastest_action, date_receieved, committee, number, description, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Error in value[3L] : Error: Error: HTTP status code 403

I have tried a few things , but nothing seems to work. Please help me.

Comment: Are you requesting many pages? When you get a 403 error that means the website has determined you are no longer able to make requests. Every website has different rules on what is allowed. The site does have a [robots.txt](https://www.congress.gov/robots.txt) page which indicates a crawl delay. If you exceed this limit your connections may be blocked. Or there may be other methods to prevent automated scraping. Rather than scraping the HTML website, perhaps you can get their data from their API instead: https://api.congress.gov/